# How to make an animation fall and disappear at the same time?

Tags: css

here is my code...

```
.poop::before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index:-1;
border:1px
}
.poop {
margin-top: 60px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Bungee Spice;
animation: poop 5s linear forwards;
animation-play-state: paused;

}
.poop:hover{
animation-play-state: running;

}

@keyframes poop {
from {opacity: 1}
to {opacity: 0}
 }
```

can i add another @keyframes? everything ive tried when I add an different @keyframe and then just add a comma inbetween animations doesnt work...

All im trying to do is get it to scroll down the page while it fades out.

edit: sorry yes i named the class poop im not trolling i was just too lazy to change it

Answer (score 0):

do like this - combination of more than one props

```
@keyframes poop {
  from {
     transform: translateY(0px);
     opacity: 1
  }
  to {
   transform: translateY(60px);
   opacity: 0
  }
}
```

A note: with the new translate function, you can replace this

```
transform: translateY(60px);
```

to this

```
translate: 0 60px;
```